# Pytorch - meaning of a command in a basic "forward" pass

Tags: pytorch

I am new with Pytorch, and will be glad if someone will be able to help me understand the following (and correct me if I am wrong), regarding the meaning of the command x.view in Pytorch [first tutorial](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/blitz/cifar10_tutorial.html), and in general about the input of convolutional layers and the input of fully-connected layers:

```
def forward(self, x):
    x = self.pool(F.relu(self.conv1(x)))
    x = self.pool(F.relu(self.conv2(x)))
    x = x.view(-1, 16 * 5 * 5)
    x = F.relu(self.fc1(x))
    x = F.relu(self.fc2(x))
    x = self.fc3(x)
    return x
```

As far as I understand, an input 256X256 image to a convolutional layer is inserted in its 2D form (i.e. - a 256X256 matrix, or a 256X256X3 in the case of a color image). Nevertheless, when we insert an image to a fully-connected linear layer, we need to first reshape the 2D image into a 1D vector (am I right? Is this true also in general (or only in Pytorch)? ). Is this why we use the command “x = x.view(-1, 16 * 5 * 5)” before inserting x into the fully-connected layers?

If the input image x would be 3D (e.g. 256X256X256), would the syntax of the given above “forward” function remain the same?

Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: Yess you are correct that the mlp, in general, are fed a 1d image the first dimension actually represents the number of samples in the batch. In general, view is equivalent to reshape in numpy. For 3d case you would do x = x.view(-1, 256*256*256)

Comment: Thanks a lot Kris!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its from Petteri Nevavuori's lecture notes and shows how a feature map is produced from an image `I` with a kernel `K`. With each application of the kernel a dot product is calculated, which effectively is the sum of element-wise multiplications between `I` and `K` in an `K`-sized area within `I`.

[image]

You could say that kernel looks for diagonal features. It then searches the image and finds a perfect matching feature in the lower left corner. Otherwise the kernel is able to identify only parts the feature its looking for. This why the product is called a feature map, as it tells how well a kernel was able to identify a feature in any location of the image it was applied to.

Answer adapted from: https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/convolution-input-and-output-channels/10205/3

---

Let's say we consider an input image of shape (`W x H x 3`) where input volume has 3 channels (RGB image). Now we would like to create a `ConvLayer` for this image.

Each kernel in the ConvLayer will use all input channels of the input volume. Let’s assume we would like to use a `3 by 3` kernel. This kernel will have 27 weights and 1 bias parameter, since (W * H * input_Channels = 3 * 3 * 3 = 27 weights).

The number of output channels is the number of different kernels used in the ConvLayer. If we would like to output 64 channels, we need to define ConvLayer such that it uses 64 different 3x3 kernels.

If you check out the documentation of [Conv2d](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html?highlight=conv2d#torch.nn.Conv2d), we can define a ConvLayer mimicking above scenario as follows.

```
nn.Conv2d(3, 64, 3, stride=1)
```

Where in_channels = 3, out_channels = 64, kernel_size = 3x3. Check out what is stride in the documentation.

---

If you check out the implementation of [Linear](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/master/torch/nn/modules/linear.py#L9) layer, you would see the underlying mathematical equation that a linear operation mimics is: `y = Ax + b`.

According to pytorch documentation of [linear](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html?highlight=linear#torch.nn.Linear) layer, we can see it expects an input of shape `(N,∗,in_features)` and the output is of shape `(N,∗,out_features)`. So, in your case, if the input image `x` is of shape `256 x 256 x 256`, and you want to transform all the (256*256*256) features to a specific number of feature, you can define a linear layer as:

```
llayer = nn.Linear(256*256*256, num_features)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Wasi Ahmad!